# Electron App (PAAS) - Is it legal to integrate WhatsApp / Skype / Telegram and other messaging?

Tags: electron, telegram, whatsapp, skype

Companies behind applications like [Franz](https://meetfranz.com) or [All-in-One Messenger](https://allinone.im) bundle various messaging service providers into a single app and sell them as a product.

Is this legal, and if not, can Skype / WhatsApp etc. block or sue them?

Answer (score 1):

What Franz and other applications actually do is not to *bundle* the applications, they only provide a convenient *mode of access*.

Since Electron is based upon Chromium, it's basically another browser with some benefits, such as native desktop notifications, remembering credentials, etc. And because they don't modify the code of the applications but instead only *listen* to the events that are already built-in, there's no reason for service providers to sue them. (And, AFAIK, no legal basis [because then they could also sue Google or Mozilla for allowing people to visit their services with their products, **which is exactly what they want by building their services**], but IANAL.)

As a side-note: I doubt that the service providers can actually detect whether a user is visiting their web UI using Franz et al. or plain Chrome/Chromium. I believe Franz does not alter the `User-Agent` string and will thus show up as yet another Chrome user.